# How can I convert a case-sensitive APFS partition into a case-insensitive one?

Tags: macos, mojave, apfs

I want to convert my case-sensitive  partition to case-insensitive on MacOS Mojave

The only solutions I've found is iPartition (which is discontinued) and ideas on how to do this for HFS.

Does someone have a solution for APFS?